# Nokia X6 headphone not working

Tags: audio, speakers

I am trying to repair a Nokia X6 headset in which one earpiece is not working. Any help on the questions below would be greatly appreciated.

1. Is there a way to test the earpieces with a multimeter to identify whether it has a problem?
2. How can I check the connectivity from earpiece to the headphone jack? Can I simply check this by connecting one end of multimeter to the wire at the earpiece and the other end to the TRS connector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You could identify whether there is any level of conductivity across the earpiece. This would tell you if something was definitively broken, but not definitively that it was working. You should compare values to the other working earpiece to know what you are looking for.
2. Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Your earpiece wire is maybe broken from inside! You can go to any Nokia care for the help. You cannot repair it yourself.

Or you should check it. You can normally press its working pad and it will lose auto
you will open it easily and then only you will check what is the exact problem. If it's wire is broken from inside, you can replace it. If yours hp is in warranty.